# opening and displaying 2 windows, arcade and cv2.imshow in Python at the same time

Tags: python, opencv, arcade

I wrote Dino game with Arcade in Python. To move the dinosaur, I use [mediapipe](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/hands.html) hand detection with a webcam. The problem is that I can not open both the webcam and the game window together.

To solve this problem I wanted to use the threading library. But the Game class had to inherit from this library, which I could not do because it should be inherit from arcade library.

please guide me. Thank you

```
class Game(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        self.w = 900
        self.h = 400
        self.msec = 0
        self.gravity = 0.5
        super().__init__(self.w , self.h ,"Dino")
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.WHITE)
        self.dino = Dino()
        self.grounds = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # Use the webcam to detect hand movements
        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands()
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

        for i in range(0, self.w + 132, 132):
            ground = Ground(i, 50)
            self.grounds.append(ground)

        self.physics_engine = arcade.PhysicsEnginePlatformer(self.dino, self.grounds, self.gravity)


    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.start_render()
        for ground in self.grounds:
            ground.draw()

        self.dino.draw()
   

    def on_update(self, delta_time: float):
        self.physics_engine.update()
        self.dino.update_animation()

        self.dino.center_x = 200
        self.msec += 0.5
        self.dino.show_walking(self.msec)

        #  ___ start Recognize hand postures ___
        success,img = self.cap.read()
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)

        lmList = []
        if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handlandmark in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                for id,lm in enumerate(handlandmark.landmark):
                    h,w,_ = img.shape
                    cx,cy = int(lm.x*w),int(lm.y*h)
                    lmList.append([id,cx,cy]) 
                self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img,handlandmark,self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)

        # Detect fisted hand
        if lmList != []:
            x1,y1 = lmList[4][1], lmList[4][2]
            x2,y2 = lmList[8][1], lmList[8][2]
            x3,y3 = lmList[12][1], lmList[12][2]
            x4,y4 = lmList[16][1], lmList[16][2]
            x5,y5 = lmList[20][1], lmList[20][2]

            length54 = hypot(x5-x4 , y5-y4)
            length43 = hypot(x4-x3 , y4-y3)
            length32 = hypot(x3-x2 , y3-y2)
            length21 = hypot(x2-x1 , y2-y1)
        
            #  ___ end Recognize hand postures ___

            # Moving the dinosaur
            if length21 < 50 and length32 < 50 and length43 < 50 and length54 < 50:
                if self.physics_engine.can_jump():
                    self.dino.change_y = 15
            
        cv2.imshow('Image',img)

        for ground in self.grounds:
            if ground.center_x < 0:
                self.grounds.remove(ground)
                self.grounds.append(Ground(self.w + 132 ,50))



class Ground(arcade.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.picture = random.choice(['img/ground-0.png','img/ground-1.png', 'img/ground-2.png', 'img/ground-3.png', 'img/ground-4.png', 'img/ground-5.png', 'img/ground-6.png'])
        self.texture = arcade.load_texture(self.picture)
        self.center_x = width
        self.center_y = height
        self.change_x = -6
        self.change_y = 0
        self.width = 132
        self.height = 56


class Dino(arcade.AnimatedWalkingSprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.walk_right_textures = [arcade.load_texture('img/dino-walk-0.png'), arcade.load_texture('img/dino-walk-1.png')]
        self.walk_down_textures = [arcade.load_texture('img/dino-down-0.png'), arcade.load_texture('img/dino-down-1.png')]
        self.walk_up_textures = [arcade.load_texture('img/dino-walk-1.png')]
        self.walk_down_textures = [arcade.load_texture('img/dino-walk-0.png')]
        self.center_x = 200
        self.center_y = 233
        self.change_x = 1
        self.change_y = 0
        self.scale = 0.3
        self.bent = 0

    def show_walking(self, s):
        if s % 2 == 0:
            self.texture = arcade.load_texture('img/dino-walk-0.png')
        elif s % 3 == 0:
            self.texture = arcade.load_texture('img/dino-walk-1.png')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    arcade.run()
```

Comment: Please add code for `Dino` and `Ground` classes

Comment: @Alderven Added.

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit your class from `arcade.Window` and add `mediapipe` code within. Simple example:

```
import cv2
import arcade
import mediapipe as mp


class Game(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(400, 300)
        self.x = 20
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.hands = mp.solutions.hands.Hands(model_complexity=0, min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5)

    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.start_render()
        arcade.draw_circle_filled(center_x=self.x, center_y=150, radius=20, color=arcade.color.RED)
        arcade.draw_text(text='Move circle with a hand!', start_x=200, start_y=250, color=arcade.color.GREEN, font_size=24, anchor_x='center')

    def on_update(self, delta_time):
        _, image = self.cap.read()
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = cv2.resize(image, (400, 300))
        results = self.hands.process(image)
        cv2.imshow('Game', cv2.flip(image, 1))
        if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            self.x += 5


Game()
arcade.run()
```

Output:

[image: Move circle with a hand!]